# What is mAh/g Specific capacity?

Tags: electrochemistry, everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, electricity

In battery chemistry I've been reading about specific capacities of various electrochemical cells as $\pu{mAh/g}$. For example, in one article it says the specific capacity of the system is $\pu{75 mAh/g}$ at $\pu{1.7 V}$.

Does that mean the a $\pu{1 kg}$ battery would give 75 x 1.7 or 127.5 Watts of energy?

Or is it some "electrod-ic" "cathodic" or "anodic" capacitance. In that case how do we calculate how much Wh/kg of power we would get effectively from a battery?

[High Coulombic efficiency aluminum-ion battery using an AlCl3-urea ionic liquid analog electrolyte](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.1619795114)

> The battery exhibits ∼99.7% Coulombic efficiency and a substantial rate capability, with a cathode capacity of $\pu{73 mA g-1}$ at $\pu{100 mA g-1}$ ($\pu{1.4 C}$).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140582/discussion-on-question-by-akshaykumark-what-is-mah-g-specific-capacity).

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Answer (score 3):

The unit mA-h/g means milliampere-hours per gram mass. However, since *mA-h* means milliampere-hours, that is, providing a stated **current** for a stated **time**, it cannot be compared with *watts*, a unit of **power**. Comparing mA-h and W is like comparing apples and barium. An automobile lead-acid battery might be rated 12 V at 60,000 mA-h (60 A-h), meaning it can provide about 20 amperes for 3 hours, or 10 A for 6 h. That is, 12 V * 60 A-H = 720 watt-hours (W-h). Each of the six cells in the battery have the same *current* rating, but at just 2 VDC, each stores 120 W-h.

To try to understand the question you might want to ask, learn about [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org//wiki/Dimensional_analysis). You can't measure area in fortnights, nor measure mass in furlongs.

Answer (score 2):

The parameters with units $\pu{mAh}$ and $\pu{mAh/g}$ express ability of a system to absorb, hold and provide back the particular electric charge. $\pu{1 mAh}$ is a non-SI unit of charge, equivalent to $\pu{3.6 C}$.

The value usually relates to the whole cell package, but as in the paper, it  can relate to one of the electrodes as well, evaluating the electrode charge storage efficiency.

Assume this illustrative case:

| Decription | Value |
| --- | --- |
| The cathode specific capacity | $\pu{75 mAh/g}$ |
| The anode specific capacity | $\pu{50 mAh/g}$ |
| The desired capacity | $\pu{300 mAh}$ |
| The needed cathode mass | $\frac{\pu{300 mAh}}{\pu{75 mAh/g}}=\pu{4 g}$ |
| The needed anode mass | $\frac{\pu{300 mAh}}{\pu{50 mAh/g}}=\pu{6 g}$ |
| The electrolyte mass | $\pu{6 g}$ |
| The supporting non-active material mass | $\pu{6 g}$ |
| The case mass | $\pu{8 g}$ |
| The total mass | $\pu{\pu{4 g} + \pu{6 g} + \pu{6 g} + \pu{6 g} + \pu{8 g} = \pu{30 g}}$ |
| The cell specific capacity | $\pu{300 mAh} / \pu{30 g} = \pu{10 mAh/g}$ |

| Quantity | SI unit | Unit relation | Calculations |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Charge | $\pu{1 C}=\pu{1 A} \cdot \pu{1 s}$ | $\pu{1 mAh} = \pu{3.6 C}$ | $\pu{75 mAh} = \pu{0.075 A} \cdot \pu{3600 s} = \pu{270 C}$ |
| Specific charge | $\pu{1 C/kg}$ | $\pu{1 mAh/g} = \pu{3.6 C/g}$ | $\pu{75 mAh/g} = \pu{270 C/g}$ |
| Voltage | $\pu{1 V}=\pu{1 J} / \pu{1 C}\\=\pu{1 W} / \pu{1 A}$ |  |  |
| Energy | $\pu{1 J}=\pu{1 C} \cdot \pu{1 V}$ | $\pu{1 mAh} \cdot \pu{1 V} \\= \pu{1 mWh} = \pu{3.6 J}$ | $\pu{75 mAh} \cdot \pu{1.7 V} = \pu{270 C} \cdot \pu{1.7 V}= \pu{459 J}$ |
| Power | $\pu{1 W}=\pu{1 J} / \pu{1 s}\\=\pu{1 A} \cdot \pu{1 V}$ | $\pu{1 mW} \\ = \pu{1 mWh} / \pu{1 h} \\ = \pu{3.6 J} / \pu{3600 s}\\=\pu{1 mJ} / \pu{1 s}$ | $\frac{\pu{75 mAh} \cdot \pu{1.7 V} }{ t \ \pu{s}} = \pu{\pu{\frac{459}{t}} W}$ |
| Specific energy | $\pu{1 J/kg}$ |  | $\pu{75 mAh/g} \cdot \pu{1.7 V} = \pu{459 J/g}$ |
| Specific power | $\pu{1 W/kg}$ |  | $\pu{75 mAh/g} \cdot \pu{1.7 V} / t\ \pu{s} = \pu{\frac{459}{t} W/g}$ |

Answer (score 0):

Let's solve your problem properly, using SI Units.

The specific capacity of $\pu{75  mAh/g}$, expressed in SI unit, is : $$\pu{75 mAh/g = 75*0.001 A*3600 s/g = 270 C/g}$$ If the battery has a nominal voltage of $\pu{1.7 V}$, it means that it is able to produce a total energy which is not expressed in watts (as mentioned in the original text), but in joules. This total  energy is $$\pu{270 C/g  *  1.7 V  = 459 J/g}$$ If the battery weighs $1$ kg, it is able to deliver a total energy of $\pu{459 kJ}$. It is not a power (as mentioned in the original text). No. It is an energy.